# Integral of dot product of vectors that oppose eachother

Tags: integration, vectors

I want need to calculate an integral to in order to calculate the magnitude of an electric field for some physics question. But I am having trouble with it and I think that I am doing something mathematically wrong. The equation that I want to solve is: $10^5 = - \int_1^0\vec{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{x}$. I chose my $x$-axis in such a manner that $\vec{E}$ would point in the positive $x$ direction (so from 0 to 1). And since we integrate from 1 to 0, $\mathrm{d}\vec{x}$ points from 1 to 0. So the angle between the 2 vectors is $\pi$. Ok let's continue: $10^5=-\int_1^0\vec{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{x}=-\int_1^0\vert\vec{E}\vert\cos(\pi)\,\vert\mathrm{d}\vec{x}\vert=-\int_1^0E\cos(\pi) \,\mathrm{d}x$.

$E$ and $\cos(\pi)$ are constants, so they can be put outside of the integral. And $\cos(\pi) = -1$. So we get: $ 10^5=-E\,(-1)\int_1^0\mathrm{d}x=E\,(0 - 1) \Longleftrightarrow E=-10^5$.

My $E$ turned out to be negative, which confuses me a lot since I chose my $x$-axis in such a manner that the vector $\vec{E}$ points to the positive $x$ direction. What did I do wrong?

If you want the full context of my problem: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340289/calculating-the-electric-field-in-a-parallel-plate-capacitor-being-given-the-po

Answer (score 0):

$d\vec{x}$ is the vector pointing in the direction of the line integral over which we integrate $\vec{E}$. Since we are going in the same direction as $\vec{E}$ as we integrate from where the voltage is $0$ V to where the voltage is $-100000$ V, and we move in a straight line, always parallel to the electric field $\vec{E}$, the integral is:
\begin{align}
V_{A}-V_{B} &= \int_A^B \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{x} \\
&= \int_A^B E \,dx \\
&= E \int_A^B \,dx \\
&= E \cdot (\text{length of path}) \\
10^5 \text{ V} &= E \cdot (1 \text{ m}) \\
\end{align}
and so:
$$ E = 1 \times 10^5 \text{ V/m} $$
or equivalently:
$$ E = 1 \times 10^5 \text{ N/C} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Manuel. Can you please tell me what the mathematical error is here: $V_{A}-V_{B} = - \int_B^A \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{x} = - \int_B^A E cos(\phi) \, dx$. Now the line integral goes in the opposite direction as $\vec{E}$, so $cos(\phi) = -1$ and we have two negative signs that cancel eachother, but then we need to evaluate this integral: $\int_B^A dx$, which will give us another negative sign. So now the E suddenly points in the opposite direction, even though the conditions were the same. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looking at your picture, if your line integral starts at the 0 V location and ends at the -100000 V location, then the vector $d\vec{x}$ points in the same direction as the electric field ($\phi = 0$) so $\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{x} = E \, dx $

Answer (score 0):

If you change the sign of $dx$, you have to change also the sign of the integral (or reverse the limits of integration). For $\vec E=(E,0)^T$, we have
$$
-\int_1^0 \vec E\cdot d\vec x=-\int_1^0 Edx=\int_1^0 E(-dx)=\int^1_0Edx  
$$

Note that here $E$ is not the modulus of $\vec E$: $E \ne |\vec E|$, but the component of $\vec E$ that can also be negative, and is positive if $\vec E$ is oriented in the sense of the $x-$axis ( the same ''sense than $dx$'')

Comment: How do I know the direction of dx in the first place? Because I think that my problem lies there. I thought that it was in the opposite direction of E but maybe it is in the same direction... How do I know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this context you can think at $dx$ as a little displacement in the direction of the $x-$ axis.

Comment: @I.Wewib $dx$ always represents an increase in $x,$ regardless of whether the integral goes from $x=0$ to $x=1$ or from $x=1$ to $x=0.$